# How to configure KeyCloak for CORS?

Tags: cors, keycloak

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'm running `KeyCloak` + `MariaDB` using `docker`, and `docker-compose`, and I also expose it to the web using nginx.

I have defined a `Development` realm and a `UserApi` client id.

Now I'm trying to test it using [their web app](https://www.keycloak.org/app/#url=https://accounts.zoodexchange.com/auth&realm=Development&client=UserApi).

When I press signin, it redirects me to the login page. But when I login and come back, I don't see my first name and last name there.

I see this in browser console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.zoodexchange.com/auth/realms/Development/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'https://www.keycloak.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You can login using `user@server.com` as email and `100` as password.

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find anything.

How can I configure CORS in KeyCloak?

Answer (score 6):

Well, sometimes docs can be really misleading.

I [found](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/the-account-console-presents-failed-to-initialize-keycloak-init-request-returns-403/8918) that it's called **Web Origins** instead of **CORS**.

It's located in client's setting and should be configured for each client separately.

And according to help, you can simply write `+` to allow origins that are valid for redirection, which you might have specified a couple of fields above **Web Origins**. Or you can simply put `*` there to allow all origins.

Comment: For more information : to edit Web origin value, we need enable "Standard Flow Enabled" button

Answer (score 3):

We need to do following things for keycloak latest UI

1. Web Origin must be like "http://localhost:4200" and should not be "http://localhost:4200/" [extra slash will create problem]
2. We need to add web origin in client scope as default.
3. If we assign client scopes to role then we have to assign this role to user