# I have created react app using vite and I have connected that app with keycloak but I am getting CORS error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, server, cors, keycloak

I have created react app using vite and connected it with keycloak but I am getting this following error -

> localhost/:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I have to show Protected.jsx component if user is authenticated and else Public.jsx

I have not use any backend till now. My react app structure is like,

```
/src
  /components
    Public.jsx
    Protected.jsx
  /hooks
    useAuth.jsx
  App.jsx
  main.jsx
  ...other files and folders
```

useAuth.jsx file :

```
//useAuth.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const client = new Keycloak({
  URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
  realm: "myrealm",
  clientId: "myclient",
});

const useAuth = () => {
  const isRun = useRef(false);
  const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRun.current) return;

    isRun.current = true;
    client
      .init({
        onLoad: "login-required",
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setLogin(res);
      });
  }, []);

  return isLogin;
};

export default useAuth;
```

App.jsx file:

```
//App.jsx

import Protected from "./components/Protected";
import Public from "./components/Public";

import useAuth from "./hooks/useAuth";

function App() {
  const isLogin = useAuth();

  return isLogin ? <Protected/> : <Public/>;
}

export default App;
```

Protected.jsx file:

```
//Protected.jsx

import React from "react";

const Protected = () => {
  return <div>Protected</div>;
};

export default Protected;
```

Public.jsx file:

```
//Public.jsx

import React from "react";

const Public = () => {
  return <div>Public</div>;
};

export default Public;
```

Comment: CORS errors are your browser telling you the server does not want you interacting with it given the URL in the browser.  This has nothing to do with your react code and is an issue with your KeyCloak config.  You need to add `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to the  "Web Origins" field of client settings in Keycloak.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507992/how-to-configure-keycloak-for-cors

Comment: I added it as an answer in case anyone else stumbles across these keywords

Comment: Thanks for the help, It worked!! I have not added `http://127.0.0.1:8080` but `http://127.0.0.1:5173` as I have to configure the client on my Keycloak pannel. Earlier I used `http://127.0.0.1:5173/` and that extra '/' was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS errors are your browser telling you the server does not want you interacting with it given the URL in the browser.

This has nothing directly to do with your React code and is an issue with your KeyCloak config.

You need to add your browser url (in your case it was http://127.0.0.1:5173/) to the "Web Origins" field of client settings in Keycloak.